# Login with google plus in ios on parse.com

Tags: ios, iphone, authentication, parse-platform, google-plus

I've integrated login via Google+ on my iphone app, all works perfect, but I want to login in ios app with Parse.com ,

already used this method but didn't work

```
[PFUser becomeInBackground:@"session-token-here" block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
  if (error) {
    // The token could not be validated.
  } else {
    // The current user is now set to user.
  }
}];
```

when I send access token in this then got error.

```
 invalid session error. error code =101. 2.refreshToken
```

Please any one can help me for login with google plus on parse.com in ios

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my last project, I did this and it's working fine .. If the user is already registered, then it will login; otherwise it initiates the signup process.

```
- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth  error: (NSError *) error {
    NSLog(@"Received error %@ and auth object %@",error, auth);
    NSLog(@"user email %@  user id %@  user data %@, ",auth.userEmail,auth.userID, auth.userData);

    NSLog(@"email %@ ", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Email: %@",[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication.userEmail]);
    NSLog(@"Received error %@ and auth object %@",error, auth);

    NSString *userName = [[auth.userEmail componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"] objectAtIndex:0];
    PFUser *user = [PFUser user];
    user.username = userName;
    user.password = @"12345"; // It will use a common password for all google+ users.
    user.email = auth.userEmail;
    [user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
             NSLog(@"Successful Registration");

            // Get the user's profile information 
             GTLServicePlus* plusService = [[GTLServicePlus alloc] init] ;
            plusService.retryEnabled = YES;

            // 2. Set a valid |GTMOAuth2Authentication| object as the authorizer.
            [plusService setAuthorizer:[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication];

            GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"];

            [plusService executeQuery:query
                    completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                        GTLPlusPerson *person,
                                        NSError *error) {
                        if (error) {
                            GTMLoggerError(@"Error: %@", error);
                        } else {
                            // Retrieve the display name and "about me" text
                             NSLog(@"Name %@  Display name %@  Person about %@ person birthday %@"  ,person.name,person.displayName,person.aboutMe ,person.image);

                            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:person.image.url]];
                            PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Profileimage.png" data:imageData];

                            PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
                            // other fields can be set just like with PFObject
                            user[@"User_name"] = person.displayName;
                            user[@"user_image"] = imageFile;
                            [user saveInBackground];

                         }
                    }];

        } else {
             // If the user is already registered, then it'll login 
             NSLog(@"error %@",error);
            [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:userName password:@"12345"
                                            block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
                                                NSLog(@"object id for me = %@", user.objectId);
                                                if (user) {
                                                     NSLog(@"user login success %@",user);
                                                }else{
                                                    NSLog(@"Error on Login %@",error);
                                                }
                                            }];
             // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
        }
    }];

 }
```

It's working fine. Thanks ..

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but it just grates me from a security point of view having a static password. A different generated hash per user (based on the username and some other app specific constants) would improve security. There isn't a great solution due to parse.com SDK's lack of extendibility.

Answer (score 2):

The becomeInBackground method requires a sessionToken you can get from a ParseCloud Application. After a while looking for an example of Parse+Google I created a Github project you can find here: https://github.com/danielCarlosCE/parse-googlelogin

I get an accessToken from google

```
let gToken = user.authentication.accessToken
```

Send it to my ParseCloud function

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("accessGoogleUser", withParameters: ["accessToken":gToken])
```

Get a sessionToken as response and use it in the become method

```
PFUser.becomeInBackground(sessionToken as! String)
```

The ParseCloud project you can find here https://github.com/danielCarlosCE/parsecloud-googlelogin

In the main.js, you need to change this var with your clientID information from Google

```
var clientsIds = ['iOSClientId','androidClientId'];
```

Comment: You are resetting the password even on login. What if we want user to use his password for login as well? Then can he still use his username, password for login as well as google login.

Answer (score 0):

First parameter (session token) that you pass to `+becomeInBackground:block:` is Parse session token, not Google+ / Facebook / Twitter.

This method is intended to be used with your own custom flow, where you get the session token differently than by providing username/password, e.g. via CloudCode + SMS auth.

You can implement Google+ sign in using something like this:

```
[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:email
                             password:@"yourSecretCommonPassword"
                                block:
 ^(PFUser *user, NSError *error)
 {
     if ([error code] == kPFErrorObjectNotFound) {
         PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
         currentUser.username = email;
         currentUser.password = @"yourSecretCommonPassword";
         currentUser.email = email;
         currentUser[@"googleAuthToken"] = accessToken;
         currentUser[@"googleRefreshToken"] = refreshToken;
         [currentUser signUpInBackground];
     }
 }];
```