# how to get session token for google+ login with parse in ios swift2

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, google-plus, swift2

I am working on one application in which using google plus login
It works fine but I want to integrate with parse also
I have [refer](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/google-plus-sign-in-with-parse) for example

```
func finishedWithAuth(auth: GTMOAuth2Authentication!, error: NSError!) {
    let token = auth.accessToken            
    PFUser.becomeInBackground(token, block: { (user : PFUser?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
       if error != nil {
           print("Error in become user : \(error)")
       } else {
           print("user : \(user)")
       }
    })
}
```

but it give me error like

```
Error in become user : Optional(Error Domain=Parse Code=209 "invalid session token" UserInfo={code=209, temporary=0, error=invalid session token, NSLocalizedDescription=invalid session token})
```

I have try also this example [Login with google plus in ios on parse.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465232/login-with-google-plus-in-ios-on-parse-com)
but it is in objective c ,try to convert to swift2 but it also give error

Please give me correct solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved issues
convert [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465232/login-with-google-plus-in-ios-on-parse-com) into swift code and its work fine

```
func finishedWithAuth(auth: GTMOAuth2Authentication!, error: NSError!) {
     if error == nil && auth.expirationDate.compare(NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending {

         let user = GPPSignIn.sharedInstance().googlePlusUser
         let userName = user.name.JSONValueForKey("givenName") as! String
         let userEmail = GPPSignIn.sharedInstance().userEmail

         let pfUser = PFUser()
         pfUser.username = userName
         pfUser.email = userEmail

         let userPassword = "\(userName)@123"
         pfUser.password = userPassword

         pfUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error : NSError?) -> Void in

          if error == nil {

             let plusService = GTLServicePlus()
             plusService.retryEnabled = true
             plusService.authorizer = GPPSignIn.sharedInstance().authentication

             let query : GTLQueryPlus! = GTLQueryPlus.queryForPeopleGetWithUserId("me") as! GTLQueryPlus

             plusService.executeQuery(query, completionHandler: { (ticket, person, error) -> Void in
                 if error != nil {
                    print("Error in execute query : \(error!)")
                 } else {
                    let aPerson : GTLPlusPerson! = person as! GTLPlusPerson
                    let imgUrl = aPerson.image.url

                    if let imgData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: imgUrl)!) {
                        self.userProfilePic.image = UIImage(data: imgData)
                    }

                    let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
                    currentUser?.username = aPerson.displayName
                    currentUser?.saveInBackground()
                 }
              })

          } else {

              print("Error in signup : \(error!.localizedDescription)")

              PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(self.userName, password: userPassword, block: { (user : PFUser?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                            print("Login Sccessfully")
                } else {
                            print("Error in login : \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                       }
              })
          }
       })
        } else {
            print("Error in authentication : \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

Hope Help to someone!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a matter of incorrect translation to Swift (as the error is generated by Parse itself during the runtime, not the Swift compiler or the Swift runtime). Try using "PFUser.enableRevocableSessionInBackground()". For more details please visit https://parse.com/tutorials/session-migration-tutorial. Hope it'll help you. Cheers.